# Can't set up absolute module imports in monorepo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig, monorepo, absolute-path

I'm trying to set up absolute imports in react/typescript project, but can't find a solution for my case. Always get same error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/App.tsx 18:14-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'common/hooks' in '/home/artem/Desktop/drum-school/webapp/src/app'
```

VSCode validation doesn't highlight any errors with my imports, but when it comes to compiling this error occurs. I tried different variations of `tsconfig.json`, but error remains. Here are my current config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions":{
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
     "module":"CommonJS",
     "moduleResolution":"node",
     "noImplicitAny":true,
     "outDir":"./public/",
     "preserveConstEnums":true,
     "removeComments":true,
     "sourceMap":true,
     "target":"es5",
     "baseUrl": "src",
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I also tried `"baseUrl": "./src"`, `"baseUrl": "./"`, `"baseUrl": "."` with `paths`, but still no effect.

One of the imports:

```
import { useTypedSelector } from "common/hooks";
```

common/hooks.ts:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import type { TypedUseSelectorHook } from "react-redux";
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from "app/store";

const useTypedDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;

export { useTypedDispatch, useTypedSelector };
```

I supposed that this error may occur because our team is using monorepo. Here is a file structure:

```
├── backend
│   ├── backend-files
│   └── backend-files
│       
└── webapp
    ├── package.json
    ├── tsconfig.json
    └── src
        ├── app
        │    ├──App.tsx     (import is here)
        │    └──otherFiles
        ├── common
        │    ├──hooks.ts    (export is here)
        │    └──otherFiles
        ├── otherFiles
        └── index.tsx
```

I will be grateful if you explain what I am doing wrong and show how to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution!

In `tsconfig.json`:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
   "common/*": ["src/common/*"],
   "app/*": ["src/app/*"]
}
```

Also add

```
resolve: {
   alias: {
      "common": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/common/'),
      "app": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/'),
   },
   extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
},
```

to webpack config file.

Comment: This is the only answer on the entire internet that worked for me, thanks.